# Play dynamically fill in application.conf from external properties file

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

My project setup looks as follows:

[image: project structure]

I would like to dynamically fill in application.conf values.

These values should be read from the correct properties file (${env}.props.properties). The correct properties file depends on the property env which is given with a run or build command (Denv=xxx).

> **application.conf**
>   key=${my.property.value.read.from.props.properties.file}
>   key2=...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried with multiple conf files (application.conf, prod.conf), which seems to work just fine. But this is not the setup I wish to have, I would prefer it as explained in the question.

Comment: Have `prod.conf` and others _include_ `application.conf` and override only those properties that need to be changed in that configuration.

Comment: As said earlier, I already worked this way and this indeed works fine, but this is not the setup I want. I want my setup as asked in the question.

Comment: Can you explain why? There doesn't seem to be much of a difference between combining different config files and what you're asking, except that what you're asking is vague and seems to be outside of the scope of what typesafe config can do.

Comment: The reason is because I want all configuration of all projects in the same file (env.props.properties). I haven't found a solution for my problem, that's why I'm asking here. This may indeed be impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Typesafe Config to load a different config file altogether by specifying flag `-Dconfig.resource=your.file.properties` as you run your application. If the config file is not a bundled resource you can use `-Dconfig.file=/path/to/your.file.properties` instead. (You can also specify an URL with `-Dconfig.url`; see https://github.com/typesafehub/config#user-content-standard-behavior for more info)

Doing this will skip loading application.conf altogether so remember to set Play!-specific properties in your own properties-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Typesafe `ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches` to invalid config entries. As api doc says; first make the changes then call above api, followed by `load()` (one solution would be to have a scheduler that calls it every x interval). 
Disclaimer - I haven't tried it myself
https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#invalidateCaches--

Comment: Didn't work for me - or at least I did something wrong.